# Is password + laptop a multiple factor authentication?

Tags: multi-factor

The definition according to [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication)

> Multi-factor authentication (MFA) is an authentication method in which
>   a computer user is granted access only after successfully presenting
>   two or more pieces of evidence (or factors) to an authentication
>   mechanism: knowledge (something the user and only the user knows),
>   possession (something the user and only the user has), and inherence
>   (something the user and only the user is)

Someone asserts me that a login password used on a computer *is* a multi-factor authentication, because someone has to *know* the password, and *have* the laptop.

I cannot explain why this is wrong. To me the laptop is the way to access the session, and not a factor per se. But it doesn't sound true. How to explain this properly?

Comment: This has been asked a few times. Let me find them.

Comment: Short answer: the login mechanism cannot be considered a "factor".